# Access is denied IIS

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis-7

[image]

Since yesterday I have this error in the IIS from my web site, and not be is the
happens, the site compiles well in VS2013 but when I upload it to the IIS get that
error took more than 2 years site running without problem.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>
> [ExternalException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command
>   being executed was
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /noconfig
>   @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\transiceberg\26691cf8\468c99a2\sxvljlta.cmdline".]
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle
>   userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
>   +3365    System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle
>   userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
>   +8591876    System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.Compile(CompilerParameters
>   options, String compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String
>   arguments, String& outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue, String
>   trueArgs) +331
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames) +875
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeCompiler.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames) +179
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +12440424
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +303
>   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean
>   isPrecompiledApp) +12978145
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +50
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +665
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command
>   being executed was
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /noconfig
>   @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\transiceberg\26691cf8\468c99a2\sxvljlta.cmdline".]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +80    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   +1142    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1193
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command
>   being executed was
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /noconfig
>   @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\transiceberg\26691cf8\468c99a2\sxvljlta.cmdline".]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12980692
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12820285

Comment: clear the temp file which resides in the following path `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Comment: delete the files and not worked

Comment: did you restarted the IIS after that ?

Comment: restart but continuous error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like certain rights have been revoked for the user. Try providing the user rights of an Admin.

Comment: the user is administrator, change to another administrator user and does not work